# What is the impact if i ignore title and content in my custom post types CPT?

Tags: custom-post-types, title, content

I am using CPTs (with PODS) and i need to "ignore" in "supports" the title and content.

I have no problem to alter the columns in the admin manage CPT list.

Also i understand that the standard functionality of WP that manages the content and title will not be there and i will have to manage my meta info in the various templates.

Other than that do i have any problem if i ignore them and leave them blank?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you supply no title, WordPress will set the title to: (example)

### (no title)

This will be shown in the list table for the post type in the admin area, within the database, the `post_title` value will be empty.

[image]

As no title is supplied, WordPress will set the slug to: (example)

### 1234

...where 1234 is the ID of the object. The `post_name` value in the database will receive the ID.

[image]

Of course if you are programmatically supplying a slug then you can set the slug to something more meaningful than the ID and this is where the **[`save_post`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/save_post)** hook comes in handy.

## Important Note:

If you supply no content (value) for the `post_content` field, then your post will be set to `auto-draft` for the `post_status` column.

So you might need to use the `save_post` hook to set a default value for the `post_content` field.

Comment: I see..This site will be very private so i will expose data in specific areas and mostly in admin area..I will chagne the admin lists screen and provide my own search...So WP will technically cover tis own ass by providing non-conflicting default values?

Comment: Yes, from a client view perspective WP will just output (no title) where a post has no title, but the slug, `post_name` column in the database will contain the post ID, e.g. `1234`, and thus that becomes the slug because you need a way to uniquely identify the object from a permalink standpoint. As mentioned you can filter the slug before insertion if you want to generate something more meaningful.

Comment: I am very happy with the id slug...The actual data for the title in the database will be (no title) or blank? Someone told me that i HAVE to put something in the title field even if i dont show/use it

Comment: It will be blank, the only thing that is mandatory is actually `post_content`, the slug will get set for you if no title is provided, but if you do not provide any value for `post_content` then the post will be set to `post_status = auto-draft` and the title then gets set to "Auto Draft"

Comment: so in the last case, i am good , correct? i dont need any of these 2 ...

Comment: also i am using PODS and i am forcing publish status..so now i amgetting an auto-draft title with published status and i am happy with it..

Comment: Ok if you are happy with Auto Draft as your title then no problem... You can always overwrite that too much like you are the status.

Answer (score 0):

The problem with not having a title for a CPT is a harder time to locate the individual "post" in the admin. Content can be safely removed, but IMO in most cases you need something that can serve as a description field and might as well use the content for that which will also make it easier to search for a specific item.

Comment: I have all of what i need in the custom fields of the CPT. Also i will change the admin screens accordingly...

Comment: Then you will just do a pointless work to recreate stuff that is part of wordpress core. In a way you might as well just use your own tables to store the data if nothing that core offers can be utilized by you.

Comment: I am using everything else wp offers. I do not need title because it does not serve me well in the current CPT structure.Also content...